# AmCharts Column fillColors all black on IOS Safari & Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, mobile-safari, amcharts

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwuwet

for some reason on the stackblitz on first start up the chart doesnt load so just make a change in the app.component.ts file and it  will load properly

This is my Chart Code

```
this.AmCharts.makeChart('chartForecast', {
    'type': 'serial',
    'categoryField': 'category',
    'sequencedAnimation': false,
    'columnWidth': 0.3,
    'marginLeft': 19,
    'zoomOutButtonTabIndex': 1,
    'startDuration': 1,
    'accessible': false,
    'addClassNames': true,
    'autoResize': false,
    'categoryAxis': {
      'autoRotateCount': 0,
      'gridPosition': 'start',
      'autoGridCount': false,
      'axisAlpha': 0,
      'labelsEnabled': false,
      'showFirstLabel': false,
      'showLastLabel': false,
      'titleBold': false
    },
    'trendLines': [],
    'graphs': [
      {
        'balloonText': '[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]',
        'fillAlphas': 1,
        'id': 'AmGraph-1',
        'title': 'graph 1',
        'type': 'column',
        'lineAlpha': 0,
        'fillColors': ['#489f58', '#8ac249'],
        'valueField': 'column-1',
        'fixedColumnWidth': 20,
      },
      {
        'balloonText': '[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]',
        'fillAlphas': 1,
        'id': 'AmGraph-2',
        'title': 'graph 2',
        'type': 'column',
        'valueField': 'column-2',
        'fillColors': ['#f89d28', '#de602e'],
        'lineAlpha': 0,
        'lineThickness': 0,
        'fixedColumnWidth': 20,
      },
      {
        'bullet': 'round',
        'columnWidth': 0,
        'dashLength': 3,
        'fontSize': 1,
        'lineColor': '#FFFFFF',
        'id': 'AmGraph-3',
        'title': 'graph 3',
        'topRadius': 0,
        'valueField': 'column-1',
        'visibleInLegend': false
      },
      {
        'clustered': false,
        'columnWidth': 0,
        'fillAlphas': 1,
        'fillColors': ['#f89d28', '#de602e'],
        'fixedColumnWidth': 7,
        'id': 'AmGraph-4',
        'lineAlpha': 0,
        'lineThickness': 0,
        'showBalloon': false,
        'showOnAxis': true,
        'stackable': false,
        'tabIndex': 2,
        'title': 'graph 4',
        'topRadius': 0,
        'type': 'column',
        'valueField': 'column-4',
        'visibleInLegend': false
      },
      {
        'columnWidth': 0,
        'dashLength': 3,
        'fontSize': 1,
        'stackable': false,
        'lineColor': '#FFFFFF',
        'id': 'AmGraph-5',
        'title': 'graph 5',
        'topRadius': 0,
        'valueField': 'column-4',
        'visibleInLegend': false
      },
    ],
    'guides': [],
    'valueAxes': [
      {
        'id': 'ValueAxis-1',
        'stackType': 'regular',
        'autoGridCount': false,
        'autoRotateCount': 0,
        'axisAlpha': 0,
        'labelsEnabled': false,
        'showFirstLabel': false,
        'showLastLabel': false,
      }
    ],
    'allLabels': [],
    'balloon': {},
    'titles': [
      {
        'id': 'Title-1',
        'alpha': 0,
        'size': 15,
        'text': 'Chart Title'
      }
    ],
    'dataProvider': [
      {
        'category': 'category 1',
        'column-1': '6.5',
        'column-2': '-5.5',
        'column-3': '6.5',
        'column-4': '-2.0',
      },
      {
        'category': 'category 2',
        'column-1': '4.6',
        'column-2': '-6.6',
        'column-3': '4.6',
        'column-4': '-2.0',
      },
      {
        'category': 'category 3',
        'column-1': '7.8',
        'column-2': '-4.9',
        'column-3': '7.8',
        'column-4': '-2.0',
      }
    ]
});
```

Now I have a few columns and three of them are filled with a gradient using the property `fillColors` now it works perfectly on desktop but on mobile there's no gradient its just all black.. I cant find any official documentation on how to solve this issue or even any other references on similar issues.

**DESKTOP**

[image]

**MOBILE**

[image]

**================================= EDIT ====================================**

Upon further research it seems for a gradient to work on mobile you need to wrap it in `<defs></defs>` tags like so..

```
<svg width="120" height="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
            <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="green"/>
            <stop offset="95%" stop-color="gold"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <rect fill="url(#MyGradient)"
      x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

*Taken for the mozilla docs on linear-gradients https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient

but since this is auto generated code from AmCharts how can I get around this??

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any chance you could whip this up into a snippet?

Comment: @SamHolmes I will make a stackBlitz

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: @SamHolmes just updated question with stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You can define **defs** property on the config object you pass to **makeChart** method. Here is an example which is working for me:

```js
config.defs = {
  "linearGradient": [
    {
    "id": "gradient",
    "x1": "0",
    "x2": "0",
    "y1": "0",
    "y2": "1",
    "stop": [
      {
        "offset": "0%",
        "style": "stop-color: #fff; stop-opacity: 0.7"
      },
      {
        "offset": "50%",
        "style": "stop-color: #fff; stop-opacity: 0.5"
      },
      {
        "offset": "100%",
        "style": "stop-color: #fff; stop-opacity: 0.01"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: hey how exactly do I pass this to amCharts?